# Getting undefined index sampleData when trying to use generate:tests command in MFTF

Tags: magento2, mftf

I am working to use MFTF, it went well upto build:project and changes in .env file but when trying to generate tests I am getting ERROR

Undefined index: SampleData
in C:\xampp2\htdocs\magento2\dev\tests\acceptance\vendor\magento\magento2-functional-testing-framework\src\Magento\FunctionalTestingFramework\Util\ModuleResolver.php:309

I am using magento 2.2.6.
Complete details regarding can be found on :

https://github.com/magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework/issues/312